# MS Access Query -LIKE x0x6

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

im using MS Access as DB and the Field im searching is a Short Text. would like to know how i could search a field and match it with wildcards. For example('x' is wildcard) -

```
x0x6 (matches 1016, 1076.....)
x06x (matches 9067, 3068....)
.
.
.
```

have search online and found sample using this - % ? #, but none works for me :/

here is my sql query -

```
SELECT COUNT(DPlace) as CounTotal
FROM tblTest2
WHERE DSide=1 AND
      DNumber LIKE '%06%' AND DDate BETWEEN #09-13-16# AND #09-13-17#

SELECT COUNT(DPlace) as CounTotal
FROM tblTest2
WHERE DSide=1 AND
      DNumber LIKE '%0%6' AND DDate BETWEEN #09-13-16# AND #09-13-17#
```

Both the sql above returns wrong result as they matches all field that has '06'. Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an explanation of why `[0-9]` works and `?` and `#` does not in your `LIKE` pattern. **TL;DR** - You are using the Access backend which runs ANSI-92 mode.

**Background**

MS Access is a unique type of software in that it is two-fold:

1. FRONT-END: A GUI .exe program and part of the MS Office Suite (with Word/Excel/PowerPoint) only for Windows installs. This GUI program can serve as a "front-end" to connect to any ODBC/OLEDB compliant "back-end" RDBMS  database such as SQL Server, Postgres, MySQL, SQLite, etc.
2. BACK-END: By default, Access GUI connects to the Windows' [JET/ACE SQL Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine) (Windows .dll files), a file-system data store, which over time has been considered the "Access database" but *any* Windows program or script can connect to it without MSAccess.exe installed. Likewise, *any* application layer language (VB, C#, PHP, Python, Java) with appropriate ODBC/OLEDB libraries can connect to this backend. In fact, when using the GUI, VBA is connected by default! So really Access is a GUI console to database (#1 definition).

   OP as commented is using VB6 (application code) to connect to the JET/ACE engine as a backend database, no where using the GUI program.

**LIKE Operator**

The above dichotomy is particularly relevant concerning the `LIKE` operator:

1. Using the GUI version of Access, its SQL dialect tends to be ANSI-plus and can interface with VBA. Hence, the `LIKE` operator behaves very similar to VBA's [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) operator. Also, the `LIKE` operator runs in ANSI-89 mode which uses the asterisk `*` and not `%` wildcard for `LIKE` as well as `?` and `#`. Even so, the GUI's `LIKE` can use percentage symbol with the `ALIKE` operator or setting the database to [ANSI-92 mode](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-design-settings-for-objects-in-your-database-0dda785a-5c19-487b-8e7f-6dd3957810ad#bm2) (and not the default ANSI-89).
2. Using the backend database of Access as OP does, the SQL dialect uses ANSI-92 mode which [MS docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-wildcard-character-reference-af00c501-7972-40ee-8889-e18abaad12d1) show include:

   > `%`: *Matches any number of characters. It can be used as the first or last character in the character string.*
   >
   > `_`: *Matches any single character within the brackets.*
   >
   > `[]`: *Matches any single alphabetic character.*
   >
   > `-`: *Matches any one of a range of characters. You must specify the range in ascending order (A to Z, not Z to A).*

Notice unlike the ANSI-89 mode, the symbols `?` and `#` are not included. But the last symbol, the hyphen, matches a range of characters such as digits, `[0-9]`. The same below SQL statement if run inside the MSAccess.exe will not return same results unless you run in ANSI-92 mode.

```
SELECT COUNT(DPlace) as CountTotal
FROM tblTest2
WHERE DSide=1 
  AND DNumber LIKE '[0-9]0[0-9]6' 
  AND DDate BETWEEN #09-13-16# AND #09-13-17#
```

Comment: Thanks for the details explanations. I am using '_' now and it works perfectly. But '[]' dont seems to work in my case. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

MS Access uses different `like` patterns from other databases.  These are [well-documented](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Like-Operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931).

From what you describe, you want either:

```
DNumber LIKE '?06?'
```

where `?` can be *any* character.

or:

```
DNumber LIKE '#06#'
```

where `#` is specifically a digit.

You can also write the latter as:

```
DNumber LIKE '[0-9]06[0-9]'
```

and this will work in SQL Server as well.

In any other database, the placeholder for any character is `_`:

```
DNumber LIKE '_06_'
```

This does not have the same effect in MS Access.

Comment: Both # ? does not work, but luckily [0-9] works :) thanks!

Comment: Hmmm . . . I wonder if you are using an MS Access front end to a SQL Server database.

Comment: im not sure what that means. im using VB6 to connect to the MS Access DB. do you know any other ways to accomplish this? as using [] works, but if there are lots of alphanumeric, special chr, it will be cumbersome.

will this works [%]06[%]?

Answer (score 0):

In Access it will be:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as CounTotal 
FROM 
    tblTest2 
WHERE 
    DSide=1 AND DNumber LIKE '?0?6' AND DDate BETWEEN #09-13-16# AND #09-13-17#
```

Comment: Both # ? does not work, but luckily [0-9] works :) thanks!